# Getting HTTP Error 503 when trying to install WHMCS

Tags: cpanel, whmcs

I'm trying to install whmcs on a hosting account from [truehoster](https://www.truehoster.com) and I'm getting "HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.", at the beggining of the install process.
The error_log in public_html is empty.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely a ioncube issue, maybe cloudlinux?
Try to change the php version, if your host supports it.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have ioncube installed ..
check the permissions of the folder where you want to install whmcs

for the error logs you can see them at /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log